# Swagger UI not generated in IBM MFP V8

Tags: spring-mvc, ibm-mobilefirst, swagger-ui, javax

I am unable to generate Swagger docs in MFP8- 8.0.0.00-20170220-180258. Also, the resources doesnt show up in mfp console.

I get the following error in logs :

[5/21/17 11:03:17:373 GST] 0000001e com.ibm.mfp.server.java.adapter.shared.JAXRSSandbox E Producing Swagger documentation for adapter efawateercom failed.
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy379 cannot be cast to javax.validation.constraints.Pattern[image]

Answer (score 0):

Message displayed on console clearly says your Adapter has one or several warnings.Fix it and try.If not please share your Adapter code or .adapter file with us.